# Set 3 UICollectionView in one UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to set 3 UICollectionView in one UIViewController
and I create 3 different outlet as you see:

```
class myViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var myCollectionView1: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myCollectionView2: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myCollectionView3: UICollectionView!
```

and for each of them

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.myCollectionView1.delegate = self
    self.myCollectionView1.dataSource = self

    self.myCollectionView2.delegate = self
    self.myCollectionView2.dataSource = self

    self.myCollectionView3.delegate = self
    self.myCollectionView3.dataSource = self

}
```

and for UICollectionView DataSource protocol, for the Section

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

    if (collectionView == self.myCollectionView1) {

        return 0

    } else if (collectionView == self.myCollectionView2) {

        return 0

    } else if (collectionView == self.myCollectionView3) {

        return 0

    }

    return 0

}
```

for the numberOfItemsInSections

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if (collectionView == self.myCollectionView1) {

        return self.allName.count

    } else if (collectionView == self.myCollectionView2) {

        return self.pharmacyName.count

    } else if (collectionView == self.myCollectionView3) {

        return self.clinicName.count

    }

    return 0

}
```

and for the cellAtIndexPath

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if (collectionView == myCollectionView1) {

        let cell1: allBrandCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myCell1", for: indexPath) as! allBrandCollectionViewCell

        cell1.name.text = allName[indexPath.row]
        cell1.phoneNumber.text = allPhoneNumber[indexPath.row]

        return cell1

    } else if (collectionView == myCollectionView2) {

        let cell2: pharmacyCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myCell2", for: indexPath) as! pharmacyCollectionViewCell

        cell2.name.text = pharmacyName[indexPath.row]
        cell2.phoneNumber.text = pharmacyPhoneNumber[indexPath.row]

        return cell2


    } else if (collectionView == myCollectionView3) {

        let cell3: clinicCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myCell3", for: indexPath) as! clinicCollectionViewCell

        cell3.name.text = clinicName[indexPath.row]
        cell3.phoneNumber.text = clinicPhoneNumber[indexPath.row]

        return cell3

    }

}
```

so the problem right now when I try to build the project they show me error 
in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

> Missing return in a function expected to return 'UICollectionViewCell'

[image]

Comment: Your "cellForItemAt" function does not return any cell if none of the condition matches. You may simply return empty cell at the end of the conditions like "return UICollectionViewCell()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- "cellForItemAt" has a non optional UICollectionViewCell return type.
  But your code does not return a cell if none of the condition
  matches.
- You can return an empty UICollectionViewCell object if none
  of the conditon mathes.

Corrected code below:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if (collectionView == myCollectionView1) {

        let cell1: allBrandCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myCell1", for: indexPath) as! allBrandCollectionViewCell

        cell1.name.text = allName[indexPath.row]
        cell1.phoneNumber.text = allPhoneNumber[indexPath.row]

        return cell1

    } else if (collectionView == myCollectionView2) {

        let cell2: pharmacyCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myCell2", for: indexPath) as! pharmacyCollectionViewCell

        cell2.name.text = pharmacyName[indexPath.row]
        cell2.phoneNumber.text = pharmacyPhoneNumber[indexPath.row]

        return cell2


    } else if (collectionView == myCollectionView3) {

        let cell3: clinicCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myCell3", for: indexPath) as! clinicCollectionViewCell

        cell3.name.text = clinicName[indexPath.row]
        cell3.phoneNumber.text = clinicPhoneNumber[indexPath.row]

        return cell3

    }
   return UICollectionViewCell()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an else statement which must return an UICollectionViewCell().

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if (collectionView == myCollectionView1) {

        let cell1: allBrandCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myCell1", for: indexPath) as! allBrandCollectionViewCell

        cell1.name.text = allName[indexPath.row]
        cell1.phoneNumber.text = allPhoneNumber[indexPath.row]

        return cell1

    } else if (collectionView == myCollectionView2) {

        let cell2: pharmacyCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myCell2", for: indexPath) as! pharmacyCollectionViewCell

        cell2.name.text = pharmacyName[indexPath.row]
        cell2.phoneNumber.text = pharmacyPhoneNumber[indexPath.row]

        return cell2


    } else if (collectionView == myCollectionView3) {

        let cell3: clinicCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myCell3", for: indexPath) as! clinicCollectionViewCell

        cell3.name.text = clinicName[indexPath.row]
        cell3.phoneNumber.text = clinicPhoneNumber[indexPath.row]

        return cell3

    }
    else{

        return UICollectionViewCell() // any cell you must need to retrun. You can return nil if you want.
    }
}
```

Hope it Helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return a cell **in all cases**, and you simply have not caught each possible situation. *[What if cell in cellForItemAt method won't be any of myCollectvion1-3 ?]*

So your solution can be done in two ways:

**1)** put this line to the end of cellForRow method:

```
... 

return UITableViewCell() // like you have done in other method using `return 0`
```

OR

**2)** **make else {}**

```
  ...       

    return self.clinicName.count

  } else {
      return UITableViewCell() // or any cell you want to create    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add one more last line like `return nil` or which return `tableview cell object` because if your every if statement is not execute then function must return something.

Second thing in your if statement in `cellfor..` function, you should use `self.myCollectionView1` not only `myCollectionView1` in every if statement so make it correct!!

Answer (score 0):

currently your collection view's `cellForItemAt indexPath` is can't able to get `return`. Because you have put `return` into the scope of `if()`.
To solve this problem you need to add one more `return` outer the scope of `if()` and it must be after the all `if()` and other conditions.

as

```
return nil or return 0
```

Here is the sample snippet :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if (collectionView == self.myCollectionView1) {

        let cell1: allBrandCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myCell1", for: indexPath) as! allBrandCollectionViewCell

        cell1.name.text = allName[indexPath.row]
        cell1.phoneNumber.text = allPhoneNumber[indexPath.row]

        return cell1

    } else if (collectionView == self.myCollectionView2) {

        let cell2: pharmacyCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myCell2", for: indexPath) as! pharmacyCollectionViewCell

        cell2.name.text = pharmacyName[indexPath.row]
        cell2.phoneNumber.text = pharmacyPhoneNumber[indexPath.row]

        return cell2


    } else if (collectionView == self.myCollectionView3) {

        let cell3: clinicCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myCell3", for: indexPath) as! clinicCollectionViewCell

        cell3.name.text = clinicName[indexPath.row]
        cell3.phoneNumber.text = clinicPhoneNumber[indexPath.row]

        return cell3

    }

return nil
}
```